# std::out_of_range at memory location c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

The compiler says my .exe can't be opened for writing.  It breaks at getline(ifs, input).  I've also been getting memory out of range errors at

```
getline(ifs, input);
std::string dept = input.substr(1, 2);
std::string sku = input.substr(3, 7);
```

I've read multiple pages on how to do this and it seems like it should be right to me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include"stdlib.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void createDAT(){
    std::ifstream ifs("C:/Users/AndrewSpiteri/Documents/Programming/C++/C++ Notes/INPUT.DAT");
    std::string input;
    ifs.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
    getline(ifs, input);
    std::string dept = input.substr(1, 2);
    std::string sku = input.substr(3, 7);
    std::string qty = input.substr(15, 3);
    std::string fill = "QTY";
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open("C:/Users/AndrewSpiteri/Documents/Programming/C++/C++ Notes/OUTPUT.DAT");

    ofs << sku << dept << fill << qty;
    ifs.close();
    ofs.close();
}
int main(){
    createDAT();
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: "exe cannot be open for writing" probably means the program is still running from the last time you ran it. Close it and try again.

Comment: I've tried that.  It's not doing it now because I closed and reopened the IDE and shut down the console.  I still get thestd::out_of_range at memory location though.

Comment: What is the first line of INPUT.DAT?

Comment: Is a question like this on-topic on SO?

Comment: @immibis Yeah, I shut down the console after trying to build it again but it gave me the same can not write to .exe problem.

Comment: @Spitz check task manager, or try Unlocker if you have it installed

Comment: @immibus INPUT.dat has this for the input: 20123456701995002.  The output is supposed to be 123456720QTY002.  Do you mean Windows task manager or is there a task manager in VS 2013?  What's Unlocker?

Comment: @Cheers - Probably. Stack Overflow welcomes enthusiast programmers.

Comment: It's also saying this in Autos when I run the debugger                     ifs {_Filebuffer={_Set_eback=0x00000000 <NULL> _Set_egptr=0x00000000 <NULL> _Pcvt=0x00000000 <NULL> ...} } std::basic_ifstream<char,std::char_traits<char> >

Comment: If you step into it in the debugger, what value does `input` have when the exception is thrown? `std::out_of_range` is expected if `input.size()` is less than the first parameter to `substr`, i.e., if `input` is shorter than 15 characters.

Comment: @Wintermute input doesn't take the getline() command and retains the initialization given to it at creation.

Comment: Then the program was unable to open the file. Check the paths and whether you have permission to open it (e.g. by trying to open it in notepad).

Comment: @Wintermute Yeah the file is there and can be opened.  It even created the output file.  getline() isn't getting the text into the string though.

Comment: There's not an empty line at the top of the file, is there? Or some sort of control character shenanigans, like a stray `\r`?

Comment: @Wintermute No I don't believe so.  All my code is there.  Can you compile and run it?